# Queueing theory - finding λ and μ from the text.

Tags: queueing-theory

I have few tasks to do related to queuing theory which I struggle to understand key points. I have few texts and I'm supposed to find λ and μ which really tells me that I'm doing something wrong. I don't have any difficulties with putting them into formulas but the process of finding them seems really difficult to me (or too easy). Perhaps it's my reading comprehension.

Could anyone confirm that I'm finding these values correctly?
Below are the two texts:

> A restaurant employs one person to serve clients. On average a client
>   arrives once every 6 minutes. The server can deal with an average of
>   15 client per hour. Assuming Poisson arrivals and exponential service
>   times....

My thinking:
λ = 6 per minute,
μ = 15/60 per minute

> A reg desk is operated by one worker who takes an average of 5 minutes and 30 seconds to complete a registration. On average, 5 people arrive to register every hour. Assuming Poisson arrivals and exponential service times...

My thinking:
λ = 5/60 per minute,
μ = 5.5 per minute

Thank you for your input.